# Difference between Backbone.Layout.extend and Backbone.view.extend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

So I have got this new project which has this line in every view.

```
Backbone.Layout.extend({ /*...*/ })
```

But when I look at the documentation for Backbone and other tutorials, it has

```
Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ })
```

Also all the views have `initialize`, `serialize`, `afterRender` functions. I tried searching it, but has not found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is using [backbone.layoutmanager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager)

> Provides a logical foundation for assembling layouts and views within Backbone. Designed to be adaptive and configurable for painless integration. Well tested, with full code coverage, in both the browser and Node.js environments.

Looking in the [source of this library](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/5ae3117659193ee3ca38f6a53b0ad2e07bda3dde/backbone.layoutmanager.js), we can see that it's just a specialized `Backbone.View`.

> ```
> var LayoutManager = Backbone.View.extend({ // line 53
> // ...
> });
> // ...
> // Expose through Backbone object.
> Backbone.Layout = LayoutManager; // line 955
> ```

It adds these [methods and properties](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Properties-and-Methods):

- `afterRender`
- `cleanup`
- `getView`
- `getViews`
- `insertView`
- `insertViews`
- `removeView`
- `renderViews`
- `setView`
- `setViews`
- `then`
- `useRAF`
- [`serialize`](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/5ae3117659193ee3ca38f6a53b0ad2e07bda3dde/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L1021) (not documented in the wiki)

The [`initialize` function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) is a default in a Backbone view, it is empty and it's meant to be overriden with custom initialization code.

To get a better understanding of what's going on in a project, look at the dependencies it loads (the `.js` files included with `<script>` tags in the HTML).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, does serialise function also comes under this layout manager library as this is not in their documentation?

Comment: @SouravPrem yes it does come with layoutmanager, but it's not documented. I had to look into the [source](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/5ae3117659193ee3ca38f6a53b0ad2e07bda3dde/backbone.layoutmanager.js). It's not that huge, I highly recommend diving into it to really grasps what's going on.

Comment: Just one last thing.. I am very new to this,  so is there any other starting point so that i don't feel overwhelmed.  How to go about learning it in short time?

Comment: @SouravPrem Take a look at the [Backbone tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/backbone.js/info), it has some great resources to get started. Also, take a look at the [popular questions in the Backbone tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js?sort=votes), you'll probably find answers to problems you didn't even knew you had.